# MultiLabelBinarizer gives individual characters instead of the classes

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working on a multi-label text classification problem. In order to encode the labels, I am using `MultiLabelBinarizer`. The labels of the dataset look like -

```
[cs.AI, cs.CL, cs.CV, cs.NE, stat.ML]
[cs.CL, cs.AI, cs.LG, cs.NE, stat.ML]
[cs.CL, cs.AI, cs.LG, cs.NE, stat.ML]
[stat.ML, cs.AI, cs.CL, cs.LG, cs.NE]
[cs.CL, cs.AI, cs.LG, cs.NE, stat.ML]
```

When I am using

```py
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
mlb.fit(labels)
print(mlb.classes_)
```

It gives me -

```py
array([' ', ',', '.', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'L', 'M',
       'N', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'Y', '[', ']', 'a', 'c', 'h',
       'm', 's', 't'], dtype=object)
```

I (partially) fixed this problem by `mlb.fit([y_train])` and I got (I printed first 10 classes) -

```py
array(['[cs.AI, cs.CC]', '[cs.AI, cs.CV]', '[cs.AI, cs.CY]',
       '[cs.AI, cs.DB]', '[cs.AI, cs.DS]', '[cs.AI, cs.GT]',
       '[cs.AI, cs.HC]', '[cs.AI, cs.IR]', '[cs.AI, cs.LG, stat.ML]',
       '[cs.AI, cs.LG]'], dtype=object)
```

Ideally, it should output the individual classes (there may be something wrong in my code). When I am using `mlb.fit_transform([y_train])`, I am getting -

```py
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with that specific class, but why are you doing `mlb.fit([y_train])` instead of `mlb.fit(y_train)`?

Answer (score 3):

It was not working because your labels are not in the desired format. It should be a list of lists. In your example, you have 5 rows of data, each with 5 labels, your labels should be a list of 5 label lists (1 label list for 1 row of data), each label list with all 5 labels:

```
y_train= [['cs.AI', 'cs.CL', 'cs.CV', 'cs.NE', 'stat.ML'],
          ['cs.CL', 'cs.AI', 'cs.LG', 'cs.NE', 'stat.ML'],
          ['cs.CL', 'cs.AI', 'cs.LG', 'cs.NE', 'stat.ML'],
          ['stat.ML', 'cs.AI', 'cs.CL', 'cs.LG', 'cs.NE'],
          ['cs.CL', 'cs.AI', 'cs.LG', 'cs.NE', 'stat.ML']]
```

then binarize the labels using `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
y_label_binarized = mlb.fit_transform(y_train)
```

and you will get your desired output, where `y_label_binarized` is:

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

and `mlb.classes_` is

```
array(['cs.AI', 'cs.CL', 'cs.CV', 'cs.LG', 'cs.NE', 'stat.ML'],
      dtype=object)
```

Comment: While loading my dataset, I am stripping away the unwanted quoted from the labels and the labels look so:
```
['cs.AI', 'cs.CL', 'cs.CV', 'cs.NE', 'stat.ML']
['cs.CL', 'cs.AI', 'cs.LG', 'cs.NE', 'stat.ML']
['cs.CL', 'cs.AI', 'cs.LG', 'cs.NE', 'stat.ML']
```
When I do:
```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
mlb.fit_transform([arxiv_data['labels']])
mlb.classes_
```
I get:
```
array(["['cs.AI', 'cs.AR']", "['cs.AI', 'cs.CC', 'cs.DM', 'cs.LG']",
       "['cs.AI', 'cs.CC', 'cs.IT', 'cs.LG', 'math.IT']", ..."],
      dtype=object)
```

Comment: Not sure what you are saying. But if you want to use sklearn package, you should prepare your data in the form that sklearn expects.

Answer (score 2):

**This solved the problem:**

First, you need to get rid of brackets/quotation marks:

```
data['labels']=data['labels'].str.replace("[","")
data['labels']=data['labels'].str.replace("]","")
data['labels']=data['labels'].str.replace("'","")
```

after that, you need to define classes between commas:

```
one_hot = MultiLabelBinarizer()

y_classes = one_hot.fit_transform(data['labels'].str.split(', '))
```

now you have the encoded labels.
This solved my problem which was pretty much similar to yours.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you call `mlb.fit([y_train])`, you aren't passing your training data to MultiLabelBinarizer - you're passing in an array with a single element, that array being your training data. This explains why your classes are weird - each "class" is one of your "samples":

```
array(['[cs.AI, cs.CC]', '[cs.AI, cs.CV]', '[cs.AI, cs.CY]',
       '[cs.AI, cs.DB]', '[cs.AI, cs.DS]', '[cs.AI, cs.GT]',
       '[cs.AI, cs.HC]', '[cs.AI, cs.IR]', '[cs.AI, cs.LG, stat.ML]',
       '[cs.AI, cs.LG]'], dtype=object)
```

It also explains why when you call `fit_transform`, you get one class with every value set to 1 - because you passed it one sample, which contained `[cs.AI, cs.CC]` and `[cs.AI, cs.CV]` and so on - it interpreted each of those as a class, and your overall data set as a single sample.

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Instead you need to call the various functions with just `y_train`:

```
mlb.fit(y_train)
mlb.fit_transform(y_train)
```